# Swift: simple way to get the first leaf of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, subscript

Considering a non-empty multidimensional array that has no empty subarrays in it, how can I get the first leaf of it?

Currently, I'm using the following construct:

```
    let multidimensional = [[[[[[Int]]]]]]()
    let firstLeaf = multidimensional.first?.first?.first?.first?.first?.first
    print(firstLeaf)
```

Is there any simpler way of achieving the same result, i.e. taking the first leaf out of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create an extension for Array, and use recursion to loop array values until we reach the first element that is not an Array

```
extension Array {
    func firstLeaf() -> AnyObject? {
        var res : AnyObject? = self.first as? AnyObject
        if let leaf = res as? Array<Any>
        {
            res = leaf.firstLeaf()
        }

        return res
    }
}


print([[[[[[[String]]]]]]]().firstLeaf())       //Optional(<null>)
print([[[[[[[1,2,3]]]]]]].firstLeaf())          //Optional(1)
print([[[[[[["B", "A", "R"]]]]]]].firstLeaf())  //Optional("B")
```

Comment: Good, but it doesn't provide type safety, the result type is "AnyObject?", not `Element?`

Comment: I don't think there is a typesafe solution at all, since Swift type system is not able to infer `Int` (i.e. Leaf type) from a multidimensional array, so this solution is as close as it could get.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
func finLeave(_ arr:Array<Any>) -> Int? {
    return arr.first is Array<Any> ? finLeave(arr.first as! Array<Any>) : arr.first as? Int 
}

print(finLeave([[[[[[[]]]]]]])) // nil
print(finLeave([[[[[[[1]]]]]]])) // Optional(1)
print(finLeave([[[[[[[23,45,5]]]]]]])) // Optional(23)
```

Comment: Doesn't look generalized enough and works only with `Int`.